# how do i extract json from Google BigQuery using a function when the field contains @ sign BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

so my table looks like this

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-08-08T09:21:57.947+00:00","@version":"1","message":"bla bla"}
```

i can extract for example the message part using the json functions like below

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(log,'$.message') AS message
```

but when i try to extract the timestamp the same way

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(log,'$.@timestamp') AS timestamp
```

i get the error "Error: Unsupported operator in JSONPath: @"
any ideas on the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where a JSON key uses invalid JSONPath characters, you can escape those characters using single quotes and brackets, [' ']. For example:

> $['@timestamp']

```
SELECT 
 json_extract_scalar('{"@timestamp":"2018-08-08T09:21:57.947+00:00"}',"$['@timestamp']")
```

See more examples on: [JSON Functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)